# Simulate non-retina on a retina display by making pixels appear bigger with a 3rd party app?

Tags: display, macbook-pro-retina

Is there a way to make pixels appear bigger on macOS so that the retina display you use simulates a non-retain display?

Comment: You mean distinct from simply changing the screen resolution?

Comment: I'm away from a Mac right now, but off the top of my head, you can change the screen resolution in Display Settings, use in-app zooming functions, use the OS handicapped Zoom function. https://www.engadget.com/2014/07/09/mac-101-use-zoom-to-magnify-an-item-on-your-mac/

Comment: No, is there a way to get a pixelated appearance without changing the screen scaling? macOS only offers to scale the UI.